# DELETE statement @ leetcode 196 Duplicate Emails

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-delete

Writing an SQL query to delete all the duplicate emails, keeping only one unique email with the smallest id. We can only use DELETE here.

https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-duplicate-emails/description/?envType=study-plan&envId=sql-i&plan=sql

Hi I'm looking through the official solution of leetcode 196, where we need to write an SQL query to delete all the duplicate emails, keeping only one unique email with the smallest id. We can only use DELETE here.

The solution is:
`DELETE p1 FROM Person p1, Person p2 WHERE p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id`

I've only seen 'DELETE FROM p1' statements from textbooks. In which case can we write statements like 'delete p1 from p1, p2' correctly?

I'm also wondering, 'Person p1, Person p2', is this statement a self join or a cross join?

Comment: cross join - [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: *In which case can we write statements like 'delete p1 from p1, p2' correctly?* 1) In any case when the logic needs in it. 2) In none case, use explicit JOIN instead of comma-style cross-joining instead.

Comment: *'Person p1, Person p2', is this statement a self join or a cross join?* Comma is lower-priority alias of CROSS JOIN.

Comment: @Akina  Thanks for your help. Why do we need a cross join here? I feel like we can also use a self join to do the same thing.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for your help. Why do we need a cross join here? I feel like we can also use a self join to do the same thing

Comment: because of the `WHERE` condition, its evaluated exactly the same as an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: *Why do we need a cross join here?* We don't need in it because the condition which includes the expressions which uses the columns from both tables is present. So your joining type is INNER JOIN, and you'd use it explicitly placing the conditions into ON clause: `DELETE p1 FROM Person p1 INNER JOIN Person p2 ON p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id;`.